# Help for identifying a shell

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, identification

After a few hours of search, I can't identify this shell. I know it's a 75 mm shell, from one of the WW (probably WWI, but can't guarantee it), found in France, but that's about it. Could be from any protagonist. 
Someone has a lead?

[image: Base of shell cartridge]

Answer (score 6):

Probably WW2, as the 39 seems to indicate year. A cartridge with the same markings is listed on a retail page [here](http://www.jcmilitaria.com/ordnance_cannon_ammo.asp?Start=50&Offset=10):

> ...is headstamped SF (Société Française des Munitions de
> Issy-les-Moulineaux (French Society for Munitions) France) over H 4 39
> (December 1939) I . The brass primer is stamped EB 211 39 (1939) .

The only variation is one entry on the primer. The SF headstamp is also listed on a table at [here](https://www.cartridgecollectors.org/headstampcodes?page=headstampcodes#S) as:

> Société Française des Munitions, (Gévelot S. A.), Place Jules Gévelot,
> 92310 Issy-Les-Moulineaux, France

So your casing seems to be of French manufacture, made in 1939.

Comment: Thank you very much!